# How can I initiate my countdown timer with a button click instead of it starting on page load?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, callback

Below in my code I have a timer that starts counting down as soon as the page loads. I am trying to use onClick to initiate the countdown once the button is pressed but it is still starting once the page loads. How can I get it to start onClick?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { View, Switch, StyleSheet, Text, Button, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import CircularProgressBar from '../components/CircularProgressBar';

function SimpleTimer() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(60);

  function timer () {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        counter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
      }, [counter]);
    
  }

  return (
    <View className="App">
      <Text>Countdown: {counter}</Text>
      <CircularProgressBar percent={counter}></CircularProgressBar>
      <TouchableOpacity><Button style={styles.button} title='start timer' onPress={timer()}></Button></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}


export default SimpleTimer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you are using useEffect, you should double check its use cases. Other than that here you are:

```
function SimpleTimer() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(60);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = React.useState(null)

  function timer () {
    if (counter > 0) {
        const id = setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
        setIntervalId(id)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View className="App">
      <Text>Countdown: {counter}</Text>
      <CircularProgressBar percent={counter}></CircularProgressBar>
      <TouchableOpacity><Button style={styles.button} title='start timer' onPress={timer}></Button></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Other than the useEffect issue, what was triggering the timer on start was the line `onPress={timer()}`. This is a typo mistake, you don't want to run that function on render but when the button is pressed, then you should have `onPress={timer}` or `onPress={() => timer()}`.

Doing my best with the english I've got :D

Comment: this is accomplishing what I wanted! but for some reason when the button is clicked its only counting down one second at a time for every button click...

Comment: Of course, sorry, you are looking for an Interval not a timeout. Gonna update the answer.

Comment: ok great thanks! no problem the explanation was great. I appreciate it.  this is mainly working accept now it is stopping to count down...it was very helpful I will try to continue working with it

Comment: i think it needs to loop somehow its only running the function one time it seems...maybe while loop?

Comment: Found it, it's an async issue with setCounter. Hard to explain with my english but easy to google. The fix:  setCounter(counter => counter - 1)